# play music on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, audio-player

I tried to get all the music files into listbox and play the selected file.

The below code is what i did to play music but unfortunately it doesn't play. Can anyone tell me what the mistake is?

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        MusicProperties music = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();

        listBox2.Items.Add(music.Title);       
    }
}

private async void listBox2_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = files[listBox2.SelectedIndex];
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(files[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Path);
            textBlock1.Text = files[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Path;

            mediaElement1.Play();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(files[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Path);` you need use the code bellow:

```
        var fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        mediaElement.SetSource(fileStream, file.ContentType);
```

Comment: I changed the code as you said, but still it's not working. :(

Comment: @Harishkutty how did you cracked it ? Can you share the details ?

Comment: Hi, use the above code as it is with the correction mentioned. Just add a separate button control and in that give the mediaElement.play() command. That's it. It'll run smooth and silky.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BackgroundMediaPlayer with background task.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx)

> You can write apps for Windows Phone 8.1 that play audio in the background. This means that even after the user has left your app by pressing the Back button or the Start button on their device, your app can continue to play audio.
>
> Scenarios for background audio playback include:
>
> **Long-running playlists** The user briefly brings up a foreground app to select and start a playlist, after which the user expects the playlist to continue playing in the background.
>
> **Using task switcher** The user briefly brings up a foreground app to start playing audio, then switches to another open app using the task
>   switch. The user expects the audio to continue playing in the
>   background.